# pretty urls with multiple queries and a php bootstrap

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hello I am having trouble getting url queries through my bootstrap and displaying a page. So I'd like to take

```
site.com?page=user-verify&username=name&hash=12345
```

and get

```
site.com/user-verify/name/12345
```

First I route all requests through my index.php with htaccess like so

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php?page=$1&username=$2&hash=$3 [QSA]
```

Then my index looks at the query and gets the page

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) 
{ 
    $query = $_GET['page']; 
} 
elseif (!isset($_GET['page'])) 
{ 
    header('location:home');
}

switch ($query) 
{
    case 'home':
        drawPage(
            'home.php',
            'Admin Control Panel',
            'This is the homepage description'
        );
        break;
    case 'register':
        drawPage(
            'register.php',
            'Register Page', 
            'This is the register page description'
        );
        break;
    case 'user-verify':
        drawPage(
            'user-verify.php',
            'Verify User', 
            'This is the register page description'
        );
        break;
    default:
        var_dump($query);
    break;
```

When I add &username=name the url becomes just user-verify. If I add /name the url becomes user-verify/name.

How can add more queries after my page query and get them to be pretty like the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php?page=$1&username=$2&hash=$3 [QSA]
```

by this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /admin/index.php?page=$1&username=$2&hash=$3 [QSA]
```

Comment: that works the urls are pretty and I am able to get the query variable but for some reason my page cannot get the files I have included in the <head>. Under my css link it shows <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'> and firebug console shows SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small>C:\wamp\www\site\admin\index.php:52:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'user-verify/badsyntax/view'</font> <i>(length=26)</i>
</pre>

Comment: would you screenshot the error ? or start a discussion with me

Comment: ![Example of Error]http://s680.photobucket.com/user/badsyntax/media/snip_zpsfphdsdsi.jpg.html

Comment: sorry for double post a little confused by syntax used to post images to site

Comment: no problem
would you screenshot the user-verify.php page

Comment: You want to see the page or the php code for the page? there is nothing in that page but an <h1>. Also when I try to go to a page without additional queries like /home the url is not found

Comment: because it requires all 3 values to exist

site.com/value/value/value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117504/discussion-between-badsyntax-and-ahmad-ghoneim).